# Java (Raspberry PI and Windows) read DYMO Scale

Tags: java, linux, windows, raspberry-pi, usb4java

I'm creating a JAVA application that needs to be able to run on windows and on a raspberry pi.

The application needs to connect with a DYMO USB Scale.

When I check with the device monitoring studio is see that I receive the data.[Device Monitoring Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UexZy.png)

I'm currently trying to read the data via usb4java.

I'm following the following:
http://usb4java.org/quickstart/libusb.html

I find my correct device.
I create my Handle.
I create my interface.

Now is my question. How do I read my data?
I try via the bulktransfer.

```
result = LibUsb.bulkTransfer(handle, (byte) 0x81, buffer, read_transfered, 1000);
```

But my buffer and read_transfered is always empty. (arrays full of 0)

What am I doing wrong?

Best regards,
Dider

Comment: What is the value of result?

Comment: I receive the following: -5

Comment: That is the error for not found. I just looked it up again because I wasn't sure. That means there is no endpoint 0x81. Can you post the device desciptor with all underlying descriptors?

Comment: Device Descriptor:
  bLength                 18
  bDescriptorType          1
  bcdUSB                2.00
  bDeviceClass             0 Per Interface
  bDeviceSubClass          0
  bDeviceProtocol          0
  bMaxPacketSize0          8
  idVendor            0x05ac
  idProduct           0x0259
  bcdDevice             2.24
  iManufacturer            1
  iProduct                 2
  iSerial                  0
  bNumConfigurations       1

Comment: Ok, I found with a tool that I need endpoint 0x82.
Now I have result 0 ==> Success.
But I still have empty arrays...

Comment: It's working now. I've made another mistake... :-)

Comment: Glad to hear it works now. :)